# Dynamically insert value from cell into a main link for the entire column

Tags: microsoft-excel

So far I'm using this format to add links to a column in a Excel spreadsheet:

```
=HIPERLINK("http://mylink.com/get?id=999";"999")
```

Each row will have an unique identifier that should follow this link format, but as expected just the ID of it must be shown to the user.

So far, I'm just copy/pasting this at every single time for the entire column, but I'm not being able to find a way to automate this. I mean, just by adding the `id` content to the cell, it should autocomplete to the link and just show to the user the clickable number for the full link.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This...

```
=HYPERLINK("http://mylink.com/get?id="&TEXT(B1;"0");TEXT(B1;"0"))
```

... will take the NUMBER (see custom formatting, CTR+1) stored in B1, make it be "text" and use it for the link and display it.

I assume that *HIPERLINK* is a localized HYPERLINK